# Storing non-binary, but non-mergable files in Git LFS

Tags: version-control, git

Is it acceptable to store files that aren’t binary and diffs between versions are not important in Git LFS? Examples of these files include:

- .obj
- .stl
- .mtl
- large .csv data dumps
  etc

I know that I can, but would there be any advantages to storing them in LFS instead of the regular repo? I've done a bit of googling but couldn't find any information on the subject.

Comment: Have you read the information on the Git LFS oficial website? Upon having a quick look myself, it seems to suggest that it's mainly made for big files, regardless of content, so you shouldn't have a problem. Did you find anything to suggest you can't use it for non-binary files ?

Comment: Or, framed another way, have you encountered any specific problems when storing these files in a regular repo, that you're hoping the LFS will fix for you? Have you made a test to investigate whether it does solve that problem? What were your findings?

Comment: @DMGregory I haven't run into any issues, but I feel like needing to store the diff between two 3d model files that would never need to be merged is more wasteful and can lead to more headaches than just storing them with their hashes. I haven't done any tests, but if nobody else comes along I will probably do a few tests next week and make an answer

Comment: @TomTsagk I didn't find anything that said it should be binary files, those are just the most common since you don't need to merge or see the diffs between them. I haven't come across anybody talking about using non-binary files in LFS though so I thought I'd ask in case anyone else has the question in the future